# AWS RDS PosgreSQL Read replica with JDBC connection string

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-aurora

Will a read replica only be utilised if the Application specifically creates a second connection pool explicitly for writes...

..Or, can I direct read requests to an [Aurora] RDS PostgreSQL Read Replica just by using connection string parameters?

https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/head/connect.html

I have tested like this:

```
jdbc:postgresql://node1,node2/database?targetServerType=master;ssl=true;sslmode=verify-full

jdbc:postgresql://node1,node2/database?targetServerType=preferSlave;loadBalanceHosts=true;ssl=true;sslmode=verify-full
```

But the RDS console continues to show 0 connections for the read replica.

I'm paying for the read replica, so I'd really like to utilise it as more than just a redundant host in case of a failover.

Comment: It looks like this is not possible without a dedicated connection pool like PGPool. Either Aurora Serverless or the new Proxy feature is probably the easiest solution.